# Is there any way to disable Tailwind's responsive?

Tags: tailwind-css

I am planing to integrate Tailwind in my existing project. I don't want it response as I resize the screen, because I have to design separately for Desktop and Mobile. For Desktop
when resize screen I want to keep my design not responsive so that user can have horizontal scroll view at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable container on config.

Add this to tailwind.config.cjs, inside module.exports :

corePlugins: {
container: false
}

It disabled all media queries on class container. Try it bro

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind is [mobile-first](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#mobile-first) by default.

What you can do to keep your "mobile" styles and add Tailwind for "desktop" is use a prefix for the Tailwind utility classes.

And with a breakpoint prefix, eg `md` or `lg`

```js
// config.tailwind.js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

You can check a simple demo here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/wef6kKa9D1

Answer (score 0):

You can design your site based on breakpoints and you can customize breakpoints [check here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#customizing-breakpoints).
 Add all classes with pre-fix `lg` or `xl` like, `lg:bg-red-400`. so this css add only after specific breakpoints.

Comment: They want to disable, not use, responsiveness.

Comment: For that need to `hidden` that `div` and after specific beak points need to display it using `block` or `relative` like, ` <div class = "hidden lg:block bg-red-400 h-10 w-10">Hello</div>`